# RestSharp API Request Invalid JSON String Response

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have some code to connect to an API Endpoint. First I get the access token, then I use that to connect to the endpoint and try to get a JSON response, however I keep getting the an Exception returned with "Invalid JSON string" and a status code of "Not Acceptable". Is this because of a problem with the way that I have formed the GET request, or a problem with the content of the response? If it is with the way I have formed the request, what can I do to fix it?

When I get the accessToken variable from the API, it tells me that the the type is "Bearer" so, I have added a header of that type.

```
    public static T SendRequest<T>(Base_URLs base_Url, string endPoint, string accessToken, out bool success, out Exception ex)
    {
#if DEBUG
        const bool _toUser = true;
#else
        const bool _toUser = false;
#endif
        var client = new RestClient(base_Url.BaseURL);
        var request = new RestRequest(endPoint, Method.GET);
        IRestResponse<T> response = null;
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        //request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = respons => respons.ContentType = "application/json";
        //request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
        client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(accessToken, "Bearer");

        //make a note of what we are about to try
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
                Debug.Note(
                      $"Sending request {base_Url.BaseURL + endPoint}"
                    , _toUser
                    , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventLogSource"]
                    , System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information, 0));
        }

        //send the request.
        var task = Task.Run(() => client.Execute<T>(request)).ContinueWith((t) => response = t.IsFaulted ? throw t.Exception : t.Result);
        if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Timeout_Secs"]))))
        {
            string methodDetails = $"{ErrorHandling.GetCurrentMethod()}";
            ex = new TimeoutException($"Timed out after {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["API_Timeout_Secs"]} seconds.");
            ErrorHandling.Report_Error(ex, methodDetails);
            throw ex;
        }

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            success = true;
            ex = null;
            return response.Data;
        }
        else
        { ////////// Code continues
```

I have tried various alternatives for the authentication and setting the content-type (I can't seem to stop the request from expecting JSON) but now believe that the accessToken is not the issue. However I can't find anything that tells me what bit of JSON is invalid - the request or the response. I don't want to spend forever debugging my code if the issue is with the response data, but at the same time don't have enough understanding to know that I should talk to them!

In order to find out whether the response is the issue, should I try to find some way to see what comes back without assuming it is JSON? I have tried removing the line `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;`, but it does not change the error. Alternatively, maybe you see a problem with my code immediately and it is definitely with me.

Comment: You are getting status code 406.  Which means the authentication passed.  The error is with the format of URI, Headers, or Body.  Every server is different.  See if it works with Postman.  Also see : https://community.bmc.com/s/feed/0D53n00007aEcKeCAK

Comment: OK, so the error is definitely at my end? I'll follow the link you put on there and see what I can learn...

Comment: Try a simple request and then get more complicated to debug.

Comment: I added the access token, url and end point to postman and sent the request (using the default Accept header of aserisk/asterisk) and it too gives 406 Not Acceptible. Maybe I should have added more info, but it seemed the simplest request I could give!

Comment: Look at the link I provided.  The OP finally solved issue.  You need to click at bottom of page MORE ANSWERS.  The answer was to change the Content-Type.

Comment: I am very disappointed to report that today there are no problems with the result. The endpoint was in some way not available without notice and no reports of the outage were provided when requested. I am sorry to have wasted your time and my own. My code works now (no changes made). Thank you and apologies. There is nothing to mark as an answer except sorrow.